# WordPress my plugin $_GET $_POST single file

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, get

I make new plugin that will be help me to insert new posts into editor.

```
add_action('media_buttons', 'jgames_button', 20);

function jgames_button()
{
$url = plugins_url().'/j_games_uploads/j_games_uploads.php?page=add&TB_iframe=true&amp;height=500&amp;width=640';
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" class="thickbox" title="Add new game"><img src="'.admin_url('images/media-button-other.gif').'" alt="Add new game"></a>';
}

if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'add'){
?>
<div class="wrap">

<h2>Add new game:</h2>
<form method="post" action="j_games_uploads.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>
        <label for="publisher">publisher:</labe>
        <input type="text" name="publisher" />
    </p>

    ...Here is more forms...

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button-primary" />
    </p>

</form>
 </div>
<?php
} elseif (isset($_POST['submit'])){
print_r($_POST['submit']);
}
```

but when I click on new button into editor I see popup window with error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()"
How to fix that?

Comment: where do you use this code? in the main plugin file? Does the error give the same line as this add_action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in form action. Don't sent form post to a independent file. Instead of it you can use `

```
<form action="?action=j_games_uploads" enctype ...`
```

I hope i could explain.